# JSON Parsing Array then Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

I am new to `JSON`, and would appreciate it if someone can help me with parsing this.

It's like parsing the array first then the object and then parsing the stuff inside the attributes array.

Any advice where I can start?

This code is how I am getting the json file

```
String json = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
System.out.println(json);
```

Shown is a sample of what I need to parse. I would need the following information:

```
"name":"",  
"attributeName": "Alternate Name",  
"attributeValue": "",  
"attributeName": "Functional Area",  
"attributeValue": "N/A"

[
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "name": "",
    "formId": 34,
    "sortOrder": 0,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "id": 67899,
        "attribute": {
          "attributeName": "Alternate Name",
          "attributeType": "Text",
          "id": 894
        },
        "attributeValue": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 67185,
        "attribute": {
          "attributeName": "Description",
          "attributeType": "TextArea",
          "id": 900
        },
        "attributeValue": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 11345,
        "attribute": {
          "attributeName": "Functional Area",
          "attributeType": "DropdownList",
          "id": 902,
          "values": [
            {
              "id": 3471,
              "sortOrder": 0,
              "attributeValue": "N/A"
            },
            {
              "id": 3472,
              "sortOrder": 1,
              "attributeValue": "ES"
            },
            {
              "id": 3473,
              "sortOrder": 2,
              "attributeValue": "IPC"
            },
            {
              "id": 3474,
              "sortOrder": 3,
              "attributeValue": "ISS"
            },
            {
              "id": 3475,
              "sortOrder": 4,
              "attributeValue": "TECH"
            }
          ]
        },
        "attributeValue": "N/A"
]
```

and then there's another array (similar to above) that need to be parsed. It's a huge file to be parsed the same way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you json is invalid check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @JohnDoe .. the json is invalid ... check the response..if the response is same as you posted here.. then this json is invalid... you can check it on http://pro.jsonlint.com

Comment: Yup, it is because I didn't copy the whole json file as it is quite big. However, the other parts of the json files are the same.

Comment: then don't copy the whole json ...but first validate json via http://pro.jsonlint.com and try to edit the json of your post to show the basic structure of json... for example if your json is {"key1": [{"json1": [{},{}]}]}

Comment: not all the values ...but the basic structure ... suppose the jsonarray contain 100 elements..the try to truncate 99 elements and update your questions

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), both available in Maven.

For example, using Jackson:

```
MyData data = new ObjectMapper().reader(MyData.class).readValue(response.getEntity().getContent());
data.getName(); // "name":""
data.getAttributes().get(0).getAttribute().getName(); // "attributeName": "Alternate Name"
data.getAttributes().get(0).getAttribute().getValue(); // "attributeValue": "",
data.getAttributes().get(2).getAttribute().getName(); // "attributeName": "Functional Area"
data.getAttributes().get(2).getAttribute().getValue(); // "attributeValue": "N/A",

// If you want to get fancy
data.getAttribute("Alternate Name").getValue();
data.getAttribute("Functional Area").getValue();
```

To do the above, you need the following mapping classes. You could deserialize into a `Map` and then dig around with `get` and casts, but I prefer Java objects with proper methods and types. The `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation allows you to map only those JSON fields you care about.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyData {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Attribute> attributes;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    // If you want to get fancy
    public AttributeSpec getAttribute(String name) {
        for(Attribute attr : attributes) {
            if(name.equals(attr.getName())) {
                return attr;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown name " + name);
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Attribute {
    @JsonProperty
    private AttributeSpec attribute;

    public AttributeSpec getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AttributeSpec {
    @JsonProperty
    private String attributeName;
    @JsonProperty
    private String attributeValue;

    public String getName() {
        return attributeName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return attributeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I check if it was able to read MyData data = new ObjectMapper().reader(MyData.class).readValue(response.getEntity().getContent()); can I just do System.out.println(data);